# Datediff question (number of days since the last appointment of each patient and the 23/09/2019)

Tags: sql-server, datediff

**Question**
List the first name, last name, gender, and the number of days since the last appointment of each patient and the 23/09/2019. The code written for the question is not quite right (I do not want multiple entries for one patient). Please tell me the right code for the question.

Code source: Microsoft SQL server

**Code**

```
Go  
Use MedicalPractice
Select Patient.FirstName as Patient_FName, Patient.LastName as Patient_LName,
Patient.Gender as Patient_Gender, 
Datediff(day, Appointment.AppDate, '2019-09-23') as
DaysBetween_LAppointmentAnd20190923
From dbo.Patient, dbo.Appointment
Where Appointment.Patient_Ref = Patient.Patient_ID
Go
```

**Appointment input data**
AppDate Patient_Ref
2019-09-17 10000
2019-09-17 10001
2019-09-18 10000
2019-09-18 10002

**Patient input data**
Patient_ID FirstName LastName Gender
10000 Luke Smith male
10001 Jess Fox female
10002 Lily Bay female

Comment: Evolve - no one should be using [old-style joins via the where clause](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 Select Patient.FirstName as Patient_FName, Patient.LastName as Patient_LName,
 Patient.Gender as Patient_Gender, 
 Datediff(day, Appointment.AppDate, '2019-09-23') as
 DaysBetween_LAppointmentAnd20190923
 From dbo.Patient,
 INNER JOIN (SELECT Appointment.Patient_Ref,MAX(Appointment.AppDate) OVER (PARTITION BY 
 Appointment.Patient_Ref  ORDER BY Appointment.Patient_Ref) AS AppDateFROM  
 dbo.Appointment) Appointment ON Appointment.Patient_Ref = Patient.Patient_ID
 Go
```